# Join two tables and getting raw values as Column with multiple associated values of other metric-columns

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables which i want to join in a particular way, one is for **competitors** data and other is **own** data. Both have same primary key cust_id (there are common cust_id in both tables).

Table 1: Competitors' table contains whether the customer has made a purchase from competitors', values are binary [1=made purchase, 0=no purchase]

---

| cust_id | comp_1 | comp_2 | comp_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| A2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| A3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

several more cust_ids

Table 2: Own data, which contains a column of the category and few columns of the metrics such as units and revenue. Customer has purchase records in multiple categories.

---

| cust_id | Category | units | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | XX | 3 | 300 |
| A1 | YY | 2 | 600 |
| A2 | XX | 1 | 120 |
| A2 | YY | 4 | 960 |
| A2 | ZZ | 6 | 240 |
| A3 | YY | 1 | 350 |

(actual data have 15 categories and thosands of cust_ids)

As an output I want table which has all data from both table being each cust_id in one raw - something like following

---

| cust_id | comp_1 | comp_2 | comp_3 | XX_units | YY_units | ZZ_units | XX_rev | YY_rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 300 | 600 |
| A2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 120 | 960 |
| A3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 000 | 350 |
| A4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |

and so on...

Can you please help me to write the SQL query to get such combined table?

Comment: Either MySQL or SQL Server. Remove excess tag.

Answer (score 1):

First resolve the aggregated data for cust_id in each tables and join them with full outer join. MySQL does not support full outer join so we need to select with LEFT JOIN then RIGHT JOIN then UNION ALL as substitution of full outer join

```
WITH
    competitors_data AS (
        SELECT
            cust_id,
            MAX(comp_1) AS comp_1,
            MAX(comp_2) AS comp_2,
            MAX(comp_3) AS comp_3
        FROM competitors
        GROUP BY cust_id
    ),
    revenue_data AS (
        SELECT
            cust_id,
            SUM(IF(category = 'XX', units, 0))   AS xx_units,
            SUM(IF(category = 'YY', units, 0))   AS yy_units,
            SUM(IF(category = 'ZZ', units, 0))   AS zz_units,
            SUM(IF(category = 'XX', revenue, 0)) AS xx_rev,
            SUM(IF(category = 'YY', revenue, 0)) AS yy_rev,
            SUM(IF(category = 'ZZ', revenue, 0)) AS zz_rev
        FROM own
        GROUP BY
            cust_id
    )
SELECT
    c.cust_id AS cust_id, comp_1, comp_2, comp_3, xx_units, yy_units, zz_units, xx_rev, yy_rev, zz_rev
FROM competitors_data c
LEFT JOIN revenue_data r ON c.cust_id = r.cust_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
    r.cust_id AS cust_id, comp_1, comp_2, comp_3, xx_units, yy_units, zz_units, xx_rev, yy_rev, zz_rev
FROM competitors_data c
RIGHT JOIN revenue_data r ON c.cust_id = r.cust_id
```